# Access Memory Usage of JVM from within my Application?

Tags: java, spring, grails, jvm, grails-2.0

I have a Grails/Spring application which runs in a servlet container on a web server like Tomcat. Sometime my app crashes because the JVM reaches its maximal allowed memory (Xmx).

The error which follows is a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" because Java heap space is full.

To prevent this error I want to check from within my app how much memory is in use and how much memory the current JVM has remaining.

How can I access these parameters from within my application?

Comment: Did you try to search Google and/or stackoverflow?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555580/finding-memory-usage-in-java

Comment: Use a profiler to find out why this happens and where, so you can fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand when OOM is thrown instead of trying to manipulate it through the application. And also, even if you are able to capture those values from within your application - how would you prevent the error? By calling GC explicitly. Know that,

Java machine specifications says that 
OutOfMemoryError: The Java virtual machine implementation has run out of either virtual or physical memory, and the automatic storage manager was unable to reclaim enough memory to satisfy an object creation request.

Therefore, GC is guaranteed to run before a OOM is thrown. Your application is throwing an OOME after it has just run a full garbage collect, and discovered that it still doesn't have enough free heap to proceed.

This would be a memory leak or in general your application could have high memory requirement. Mostly if the OOM is thrown with in short span of starting the application - it is usually that application needs more memory, if your server runs fine for some time and then throw OOM then it is most likely a memory leak.

To discover the memory leak, use the tools mentioned by people above. I use new-relic to monitor my application and check the frequency of GC runs.

PS Scavenge aka minor-GC aka the parallel object collector runs for young generation only, and PS MarkAndSweep aka major GC aka parallel mark and sweep collector is for old generation. When both are run – its considered a  full GC. Minor gc runs are pretty frequent – a Full GC is comparatively less frequent. Note the consumption of different heap spaces to analyze your application.

You can also try the following option -

If you get OOM too often, then start java with correct options, get a heap dump and analyze it with jhat or with memory analyzer from eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError   -XX:HeapDumpPath=path to dump file

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Grails Melody Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) that display's the info in the url `/monitoring` relative to your context.

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent this error I want to check from within my app how much
>   memory is in use and how much memory the current JVM has remaining.

I think that it is not the best idea to proceed this way. Much better is to investigate what actually breaks your app and eliminate error or make some limitation there. There could be many different scenarios and your app can become unpredictable. So to sum up - capturing memory level for monitoring purpose is OK (but there are many dedicated tools for that) but in my opinion depending on these values in application logic is **not recommended** and **bad practice**

Comment: Can you name some dedicated tools?

Comment: I worked with JProfiler with complex distributed system and I can say that this tool is very helpful - nice features for analyzing threads(statuses, thread dumps), memory(included list of objects and their sizes) and few others. It has free trail for 10 days so it's worth to try. There are also tools included in JDK like visualvm mentioned by Mark R. But definitely try JProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would use a profiler to profile your application and JVM, rather than having code to monitor such metrics inside your application.

Profiling is a form of dynamic program analysis that measures, for example, the space (memory) or time complexity of a program, the usage of particular instructions, or frequency and duration of function calls

Here are some good java profilers:

http://visualvm.java.net/ (Free)

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html (Paid)